# How to stop Flash from identifying source

Tags: mac, browser-addons, flash-player, tor

See title. How do I stop Adobe Flash from transmitting ip address or other identifying info when I'm in a browser-based video chat

Comment: Pretty much the only solution would be to configure the browser to use a proxy or use a VPN service.

Comment: I believe Tor uses the equivalent of proxies, but using Torbrowser doesn't appear to do much - Flash seems to have its own communication channel for transmitting this info ...

Comment: Are you sure you are transmitting your actual information instead of the proxy information when using Torbrowser?  Flash isn't magically cable to pickup your actuall information if Firefox ( which is what Torbrowser is based on ) is setup to use a proxy.

Comment: "IP Address" is not "info". It is **part of the message itself**. It is impossible (usually) to send an IP packet over the public Internet with a forged source IP address, because a router somewhere along the line (probably at your ISP) will know that it didn't actually originate from the IP your packet claims it did. As soon as a valid packet with your correct source IP makes its way to the remote client for the peer to peer video chat,  they "have your IP address". Now, granted, they can't do a whole lot with this aside from try to hack you, but if you're trying to prevent them from ...

Comment: ...obtaining your IP, and you're making a **peer-to-peer** connection, you are not going to be successful in this. Unless you use a VPN service, which routes traffic from your IP address to a remote server that then routes it to the destination on your behalf. But then your remote peer on the other end would know the IP address of the VPN, and if you're the only one using it, or if the owner of the VPN agrees to tell them your real IP address, you're *still* revealed. You should instead try to conduct business in a way that them having your IP address isn't a problem.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, Tor can mask the originator because http requests are between client and server and addresses are easily translated by proxies, but the chats are always peer-to-peer, so their very nature requires both IP addresses (modulo the VPN solution).

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily.

Since there are no usermode controls on Flash's sandbox, your best bet is to run it inside of a virtual machine, and route all of that virtual machine's network traffic through a remote VPN/proxy.

Comment: And you can't hack the sandbox, I take it - or it's a hassle?

Comment: It's not so much about hacking; I'm sure you could grab the source code to chromium's sandbox-- The catch is you'd have to be a very competent C/C++ expert programmer to make any useful modifications to it. There's no simple configuration option where you can set "Don't expose network adapters to Flash objects"